# pgAdmin - PostgreSQL. ERROR: ОШИБКА

Tags: java, postgresql, pgadmin4

Написал запрос в pgAdmin - PostgreSQL
SELECT * FROM "user";
WHERE user_age < 25;

Ругается на вторую строчку с ошибкой ERROR: ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "WHERE"), если заменить WHERE на ORDER BY скажем, точно такая же история.
Если убрать строчку WHERE user_age < 25; то запрос отрабатывает нормально [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ; уберите перед where

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select .. from .. where` это одна инструкция и `;` там не нужна внутри инструкции